# Using OpenStreetMap data in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, openstreetmap, arcgis-editor-osm

I posted this on the OSM help page but it was suggested I try here instead:

I'm new to OSM data and I'm using the ArcGIS editor for OpenStreetMap within ArcMap. The data downloads correctly but the table doesn't seem to include the 'name' field (which is the field I really need).

When I follow the instructions listed [here](https://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Extracting%20Specific%20Tags&referringTitle=Download%20Data%20from%20OSM), I receive "ERROR 0008000: The value is not a member of ALL." It works when 'ALL' is there but if I try and add 'name' it fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: see http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp00000004000800.htm

Comment: Actually I've read the documentation on the error which I understand, but this post (https://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Extracting%20Specific%20Tags&referringTitle=Download%20Data%20from%20OSM) makes it seem as if a.) the error shouldn't occur or b.) it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Which version of the ArcGIS Editor for OSM are you using?  Would you be able to use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with this and any other details requested via Comments, please?  I think it would also help if you listed more of your exact steps so that others can try to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: There is another way: you can use OSM data in ArcMap without ArcGIS editor for OpenStreetMap. For example, you can create your own tile server with OSM, or your can add wms server => then in ArcMap you can display OSM data (ArcMap supports WMS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be an option for you to use already converted osm data?

You can download shapefiles here: http://download.geofabrik.de/

They of course have to select a subset of all the possible OSM tags. If you need some tags that are not in those shapefiles by default, you can generate your own shapefiles using the HOT (Humanitarian Openstreetmap Team) export tool: http://export.hotosm.org/ All you need here is a JOSM preset file in which you specify what tags you want. More here: http://visualtags.hotosm.org/

Comment: I did end up downloading the shapefiles from http://download.geofabrik.de/.  For some reason though the labels were still acting strange (only a portion were showing and different ones would draw at different scales despite plenty of room) but I was able to export the polygon data to points (in this instance I was trying to get building names) and eventually they all displayed.

Comment: Additionally you can have a look at various resources here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefile